# Apex Batch jobs logs?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I am running a batch job in my Sandbox from execute anonymous. When I create an object of the apex batch class and use `database.executebatch(obj,50);` I can run the apex class which does the batch process and open up a log in developer console. However I can see logs related to start() method of the batch class. I do not see logs related to what happened in execute() and finish() method. Where should I look for these log files if I am executing batch manually instead of using scheduler job.

Comment: You should be able to see in same place. Batch jibs are asynchronous so, it may take some time depending on system load.

Comment: Yes , the log file opens up immediately in Developer Console. Is that log is all I have? or is there any where else I should look for additional log file.  When I searched online to see why my debug statements in execute() method is not showing up in the log, I read that start,execute and finish all are in separate log files? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, each execute call shown as separate log file.

Comment: I have only one execute method though so should I able to see it in the log file which shows up when I run the apex class in execute anonymous?

Comment: Yes there should be 3 log files, 1. Execute Anonymous 2. Execute method 3. Finish method. Batch run in asynchronous mode so you may get these files after a delay.

Comment: I ran this batch class in the morning and I got only one log. No other logs popped up on developer console till evening. Should I be checking something? My name shows up in debug logs- User trace Flags

Comment: As I wrote in answer, you would check that you have setup debug traces correctly.

Comment: I checked Debug logs->User Trace Flags and I see my name present there with log type - DEVELOPER_LOG. Is that what you wanted me to verify?

Comment: Yes, edit and reset it.

Comment: Thanks, So I might get the logs for execute() method after like 3-4hrs?

Comment: No, it should not take more than 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. It did not take much long to appear. Just few minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to see in same place. Batch jobs are asynchronous so, it may take some time depending on system load. It create separate file for `execute` and `finish` call.

Also make sure that you have setup debug logs for current logged use in *Monitoring > Debug Logs*.

With winter'16 you need to set up "User Trace Flags" with debug level for `apex:DEBUG`, `system:DEBUG` to see logs.